# Will any QR scanners fail to read a code with a sub-optimal mask pattern choice?

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner

The QR code specification requires an optimal choice of mask to avoid patterns that are difficult to scan. If the rules for this choice are ignored and one of the mask patterns is chosen arbitrarily, but the scanner is not confused by the pattern while scanning it, will there be any decoding problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The mask that is used is recorded in the QR code itself, in the area around the finder patterns. As long as that is read correctly, the mask will be correctly removed before decoding. It doesn't matter whether it's actually the optimal pattern or not. Any mask may be used in theory.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, sometimes. Due ISO/IEC 18004:2000 (8.8), masking is used for:

1. balancing dark and light modules,
2. avoiding Position Detection pattern.

The first one will affect on version detection, which is made provisionaly for versions of QR code less than 7.

The second one will affect on position patterns detection.

Both these steps should be done before reading Format Information and applying mask to QR code while decoding.